# text scan iterations

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have some files to process , but i have missing files in middle
i am using

> for i=1:file;
>
> fid = fopen(['Raw',num2str(i),'.txt']);
>
> D = textscan(fid1,'%*f %f%*f%*f%*f%*f%f%*[^\n]','delimiter',';', 'headerlines',50,'CollectOutput', 1);
>
> fclose(fid);

Now the rest of program works well when i have files in order

i.e,  100,200 any number of files in my folder in order as Raw1.txt, Raw2.txt, Raw3.txt, ....

I get into trouble as soon as there are missing files like   Raw1.txt, Raw4.txt, Raw5.txt

How do i iterate my text scan so it can ignore the file numbering?

Thanks

Edit :

By missing files i mostly mean numbers after 'Raw'

My files get generated as Raw1, Raw2, Raw3............ Raw400.txt

When all the files are in order and present i have no problem.

when i have some missing or jumps  like for example
Raw1 . Raw2.......... Raw10, Raw15, Raw16
I have trouble as there is jump from Raw10.txt to Raw15.txt
I have same problem if my files start at anything other than Raw1.txt

Answer (score 1):

look for [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) in matlab documentation. Something like this should work:

```
for i=1:file;

    if exist(['Raw',num2str(i),'.txt'], 'file')
       % File exists!
       fid = fopen(['Raw',num2str(i),'.txt']);
       D = textscan(fid1,'%*f %f%*f%*f%*f%f%f%[^\n]','delimiter',';', 'headerlines',50,'CollectOutput', 1);
       fclose(fid);
    end

end
```

Note that  `exist(Name, 'file')` checks for the **file's directory** too, so either give the full file name (i.e. with path), or try something like `if exist(Name, 'file') == 2`